# Shuffling the results from an NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, core-data, random, nsarray, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using an `NSFetchedResultsController` to pull a few thousand results out of a Core Data structure and display them in a `UITableView`. I have a few available options that perform fetches with predicates and display that updated data, such as search by keyword, sort by author, etc.

I'd like to randomly shuffle the order before they're displayed. I've created a category of `NSArray` with a `shuffle` method which works perfectly, but calling that method on `[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]` has no effect, the data remains unchanged. I'm assuming that this is because `fetchedObjects` is `readonly`, and that I'd need to make a copy.

I've made that copy, but the snag I've hit is in making that new array co-exist peacefully with the `fetchedObjects` array. I can go off to various detail views and modify the content, so I'm trying to ascertain how I can keep `fetchedObjects` and my `shuffledFetchedObjects` array in sync, even though their content is in a different order.

Here's my simple little `shuffle` category:

```
- (NSArray *) shuffle {
    NSMutableArray *tmp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self];
    for (int i = [tmp count] - 1; i > 0; i--) [tmp exchangeObjectAtIndex: arc4random() % (i + 1) withObjectAtIndex: i];
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray: tmp];
}
```

What options do I have for achieving this?

Comment: Do you really need a FRC in your case? A FRC is useful to display a table view with *automatic updates* if objects are inserted, deleted or modified. - What do you expect if a new object is inserted? Where should it appear in the table view?

Comment: There's no means of adding entries here, just removing them and marking them as favourites, and sorting, etc.

Comment: But then you don't need a FRC. Just fetch the results with `NSArray *results = [context executeFetch:request error:&error];`, shuffle the `results` array and use the shuffled array as table view data source.

Comment: Will this still keep updated if I call `reloadData` on the `tableView`? I do that a lot.

Comment: I don't quite understand your last question. `reloadData` queries the data source methods `numberOfRows...` and `cellForRow...`, and these methods would get the information from the shuffled array.

Comment: Excellent, okay, I'll give that a try. Drop an answer if you want me to mark it (if this works!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem by using a `shouldShowShuffled` boolean value, which I flip on and off depending on what filter was selected. If it's turned `ON`, I show results from my copy of the FRC's results, which are shuffled. If it's turned `OFF`, I show the `fetchedObjects` directly from the FRC.

I'm updating the shuffled array at any point when the `fetchedObjects` array would be updated, so it's always up to date.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of modifying the `fetchedObjects` of a fetched results controller (FRC). Instead of shuffling the fetched objects, you could use a random *index* to map the FRC row numbers to table view row numbers and vice versa.

But if you don't really need the change tracking features of the FRC, then it is easier to do a simple fetch:

```
NSArray *results = [context executeFetch:request error:&error];
```

shuffle the result:

```
NSArray *shuffledResults = [results shuffle];
```

and use `shuffledResults` in the data source methods `numberOfRows...` and `cellForRow...`.
Then you don't have to keep anything in sync.

*Update:* If you have sections, then you need the FRC, and an array of arrays (1. level is the section number, 2. level the row number) for the shuffled objects. You can fill it like this:

```
// ... after [frc performFetch:&error] ...
self.dataSource = [NSMutableArray array]; // a NSMutableArray property of your view controller
for (NSUInteger section = 0; section < [[frc sections] count]; section++) {
    NSArray *objects = [[frc sections][section] objects]; // all objects of this section
    [self.dataSource addObject:[objects shuffle]];
}
```

Then, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you access the array like this:

```
NSManagedObject *obj = self.dataSource[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
```

(A completely different approach would be to add an attribute "randomOrder" to the entity, assign random numbers to each object and add a sort descriptor for "randomOrder" to the fetch request.)

Comment: So in this case, at whichever points I perform a fetcb using the FRC (there are maybe six or so instances of this with different fetches, predicates, sort descriptors, etc.) I would substitute fetching the context directly?

Comment: So I'm running into a problem with this approach: section header titles. I get those via: `[[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex: section] name]` and I can't do that with a separate array. How can I get around that?

Comment: @lukech: OK, I had silently assumed that you don't have sections. Do you want to shuffle the objects within each section? Then you need an array of arrays (one for each section). - A completely different approach would be to add an attribute "randomOrder" to the entity, assign random numbers to each object and add a sort descriptor for "randomOrder" to the fetch request. - I will update my answer if I have a better idea, or perhaps someone else comes up with a more helpful answer.

Comment: Ideally within each section, yes.

Comment: So when exactly would I fill that array of arrays? When the user taps "Filter by Section" or whatever, or would I do it in advance?

Comment: @lukech: I don't know the structure of your program and what the user can do. But each time the filter criteria change, you have to assign a new fetch request to the FRC, call `performFetch`, and then fill that array.