# Random results from NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

I have some data in my entity. How can I get all entries in a random order. ie I wanna shuffle all entries again and again.

I found solution of this question here: [Shuffling the results from an NSFetchedResultsController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357888/shuffling-the-results-from-an-nsfetchedresultscontroller). But I would like to get `NSFetchedResultsController` with results. Any ideas? Maybe using `NSPredicate` or `NSSortDescriptor`?

Comment: What of the FRC do you need as you want to subvert the sort? Just the change detection? The other question holds a number of suggested solutions already, which did you try and how didn't they work?

Comment: Some elegant solution using `NSPredicate`. If I am setting nil to `NSFetchedRequest.predicate` i see all entries but these results are always in the same order.

Comment: I have no idea. If only to use different sorting. But their number is not infinite.

Comment: Again, if I use a predicate, it is not all entries are output

Comment: A FRC requires a sort descriptor (which can only sort on persistent attributes of the entity), therefore the FRC result is always very deterministic.

Comment: Also note that a *predicate* is only for filtering (i.e. reducing the result set according to some criteria). The predicate has no influence on the sort order.

Comment: I see. Then can use only several `NSSortDescriptor` and change their count and order for field sortDescriptors of `NSFetchRequest`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclass `NSSortDescriptor` to change the default sorting behavior. Something like this should work:

```
@interface RandomSortDescriptor : NSSortDescriptor 
@end

@implementation RandomSortDescriptor

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone*)zone
{
    return [[[self class] alloc] initWithKey:[self key] 
                           ascending:[self ascending] selector:[self selector]];
}

- (id)reversedSortDescriptor
{
    return [[[self class] alloc] initWithKey:[self key] 
                           ascending:![self ascending] selector:[self selector]];
}

- (NSComparisonResult)compareObject:(id)object1 toObject:(id)object2 
{
    NSUInteger random = arc4random_uniform(3);
    switch (random)
    {
       case 0:
          return NSOrderedSame
       case 1:
          return NSOrderedDescending;
       case 2:
          return NSOrderedDescending;
     }
}

@end
```

Comment: Depending on the sort algorithm internally, this may produce biased results. See http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/compare.html. If you need unbiased results, assign random values to a sort property on your entities and sort by that.